# Refresh a jQuery Accordion in a Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery

I am attempting to use jQuery Accordion in a Lightning component.

It uses code like this:

```
<div id="ticket-event-list">

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.insights}" var="insight" indexVar="indx">
        <div class="event" id="{!'event'+indx}">{!insight.Name}</div>
        <div class="content"> <c:InsightCell insight="{!insight}"/></div>
    </aura:iteration>
</div>
```

Note that I am trying to respond to changes using:

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.insights}" action="{!c.handleValueChange}"/>
```

In order to refresh the accordion after I update the values like this:

```
 $("#ticket-event-list").accordion("refresh");
```

The issue is that the notification seems to be coming before the `aura:iteration` has finished updating the component. If I use the refresh command in the console after it's rendered incorrectly, I can get it to refresh and show correctly.

Looking at the Chrome Lightning Inspector I see that the event is correctly calling my `handleValueChange` method, but it seems to be called either in parallel to the iteration, or before it... and I don't seem to have control over the order:

```
<aura:iteration globalId="378:2;a" items="[4]" var="insight" indexVar="indx" loaded="true" template="[2]" forceServer="false">
c.itemsChange
c.markup://aura:valueChange

<c:InsightList globalId="372:2;a" insights="[4]" omnifocus="true">
c.handleValueChange
```

Is there some other `aura event` that gets called after the iteration has finished doing it's thing?

[Here are the sources for my list component](https://github.com/xmas/current-actions-salesforce/tree/master/CurrentActions/metadata/aura/InsightList)

Comment: Quick follow-up, I was able to get a hack in place using: 
`setTimeout(function () {$("#ticket-event-list").accordion("refresh");}, 0);
`
 to call my refresh function on the value change event.

Comment: put that as an answer .looks on to me ..

Comment: There is now a `lightning:accordian` component that you should consider. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library?page=lightning:accordion

Answer (score 0):

Promoting my comment to answer:

I was able to get a hack in place using:

```
setTimeout(function () {
   $("#ticket-event-list").accordion("refresh");}, 
   0);
```

to call my refresh function on the value change event. Note that this is the same as `_.defer()`. From the underscore docs:

> Defers invoking the function until the current call stack has cleared,
>   similar to using setTimeout with a delay of 0. Useful for performing
>   expensive computations or HTML rendering in chunks without blocking
>   the UI thread from updating. If you pass the optional arguments, they
>   will be forwarded on to the function when it is invoked.

So this while this "works", it's not ideal since there can be a brief flash of UI updating. Hopefully aura will gain a "finally after change" event in the future.

Comment: Have you tried putting your JQuery code inside the renderer? That's the only place you should be putting anything that modifies the DOM directly. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm. That's going to be your "finally after change" event.

Comment: Just tried the renderer.  I'll admit that I'm a very novice JS programmer (I come from the server and iOS). 

First, the renderer was getting called prior to all scripts getting loaded, so I had to add logic to use the jQuery methods ("$" was not initialized).

Second, it wasn't getting called reliably on change.

From the docs I agree that the renderer should be the place to do this, but I haven't seen examples with this level of complexity showing it working yet.. or I don't understand the ones I've seen :)

Comment: Which renderer methods did you use? afterRender is the place to put custom modification for initial rendering, but reRender is the place to put updates that occur as a result of attribute changes. unrender is where you'd put clean up code. It really is better to familiarize yourself with the framework rendering lifecycle and work with it rather than putting in various setTimeout hacks, as these are not going to be reliable when your component is sharing the page with many other components.